# What is the relationship between NGINX and ICECAST?

Tags: webserver

I tried to make a web radio station on my ubuntu machine using NGNIX and ICECAST. I know NGINX is a web server and I installed on my machine. Also, ICECAST in a streaming media (audio/video) server and I installed. I do not know how they interact with each other. What is the relationship between NGINX and ICECAST? What is different between them?

Answer (score 0):

**Nothing at all.  However...**

Both NGINX and ICECAST operate on their own ports and are completely independent services.

If, however, you want to run them on the **same** port (usually port 80), then you will need to configure NGINX to act as a proxy for ICECAST.